# Finding the sum of an alternating infinite series with $\pi$ in it.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem:

Does the following series converge? If it does, find the sum.
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}  \dfrac{ \left( -1 \right) ^n \pi^{2n} }{n! }$$

Answer:

First, I believe that the series is convergent because it is an alternating sign series, the terms get progressively smaller and
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$.

Recall that:
$$ \cos x =
 \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}  \dfrac{ \left( -1 \right) ^n {x}^{2n} }{(2n)! } $$
As such, I am thinking that I can force the second series to look like the first series by picking the right value of $x$. However, I do not know what the right value of $x$ is.

Recall that:
$$ e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!} $$
I am wondering if I can force this third series to look the first series
by picking the right value of $x$. However, I do not know what the right value of $x$ is.

Comment: This is $\exp (-\pi^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Instead use $e^{-x}$. The sum equals to $e^{-\pi^2}$.